# applescript - extract filename from posix path

Tags: applescript

```
set p to "/Users/myAccount/Desktop/testfilename.txt"
set a to POSIX file p
```

I would like to extract "testfilename.txt" from the posix path above?  Anyone know how to go about to do that?

Comment: If you want just the file name you can use: `set a to do shell script "basename $HOME/Desktop/testfilename.txt" as string`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
set yourpath to ("/YOUR/PATH/HERE/file.ext") as POSIX file
do shell script "basename " & quoted form of POSIX path of yourpath
```

This should work for files and folders as well. 
I used `"basename " & quoted form of`... because AppleScript and shell script handle spaces in directories quite in a different way, that should allow you to use also paths with spaces in it.